# express.use in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, rest, express

I have finished Nodejs express app and I want to deploy it to Firebase functions when I run firebase emulator.

I am not able to reach my app.use routes.

I am able to reach

```
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
         res.send('Heloo ti Invest4You doslo je dop app.js');
     } )
```

This is my index.js in functions

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import app from '../app.js';
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
// 
export const invest = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

my app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan  from 'morgan';

import rateLimit  from 'express-rate-limit';
import helmet  from 'helmet';
import mongoSanitize  from 'express-mongo-sanitize';
import xss  from 'xss-clean';
import hpp from 'hpp';
import path  from 'path'

import AppError from './utils/appError.js';
import companyRouter from './routs/company.js'
import userRouter from './routs/user.js'


const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// 1) GLOBAL MIDDLEWARES
// Set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// Development logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
// app.use(bodyParser({
//   json: { limit: '50mb', extended: true },
//   urlencoded: { limit: '50mb', extended: true }
// }));
// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!'
});
app.use('/api', limiter);

// Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '250kb' }));

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

// Prevent parameter pollution
app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: []
  })
);

// Serving static files
// app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

// Test middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  // console.log(req.headers);
  next();
});
// app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../client/build')));

// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/build', 'index.html'));
// });
// // 3) ROUTES
app.use('/api/v1/companies', companyRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Heloo ti Invest4You doslo je dop app.js');
} )
// app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviewRouter);

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});

// app.use(globalErrorHandler);

export default app;
```

My router

company.js

```
import express from 'express';

import {getAllCompanies, getOneCompany, createCompany, updateCompany, deleteCompany, likeCompany, newPrice, GetAllPrices} from '../controllers/company.js'
import { protect } from '../controllers/auth.js'
import { createNews, getAllNews } from '../controllers/newsController.js';

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', getAllCompanies);
router.get('/ir', getAllNews);
router.get('/myAccount', GetAllPrices);
router.get('/:id',  getOneCompany);
router.post('/', createCompany);
router.post('/myAccount',  newPrice);
router.post('/ir',  createNews);
router.patch('/:id/likeCompany',protect, likeCompany);
router.patch('/:id', updateCompany);
router.delete('/:id', deleteCompany)

export default router;
```

I get local address

```
http://localhost:5001/investfouyou/us-central1/invest
```

and that gets me

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
             res.send('Heloo ti Invest4You doslo je dop app.js');
         } )
```

but I need to get

```
http://localhost:5001/investfouyou/us-central1/invest/api/v1/companies
```

to access my router

I want to get to these two lines

```
   app.use('/api/v1/companies', companyRouter);
   app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
```

Please help

Comment: try to comment this block and check again  
`app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});`

Comment: I have tried it nothing changed, still not able to get end points I want